# asn1c compiler not compiling the asn files

Tags: c, asn.1

I have just installed the asn1c on my windows7 machine, 
 and I am trying to compile the S1AP specification from 3GPP.

```
 I have C:\Users\sdk\Desktop\Asn_Practice> where I put all my asn files.I
```

used the  following command to compile.but it shows some error.I have given it below.If I have given the right command ,I copied it from the help document .
If any suggestions please help.

```
C:\Users\sdk\Desktop\Asn_Practice>"C:\Program Files\asn1c\asn1c"  -fnative-types S1apCommonDefinitions.asn1 S1apConstantDefinitions.asn1       S1apContainerDefinitions.asn1 S1apElementaryProcedureDefinitions.asn1  S1apInformationElementDefinitions.asn1 S1apPduDefinitions.asn1
```

ASN.1 grammar parse error near line 105 (token "{"): syntax error, unexpected '{
'
Cannot parse "S1apInformationElementDefinitions.asn1"

Thanks,
  SDK

Comment: Please post the `S1apInformationElementDefinitions.asn1`, or preferrably, the smallest version of the file that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The open source asn1c compiler does not support many of the items used in specs like this such as classes, information objects, information object sets, etc..